# SE Android app wrongly showing questions as unanswered

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

[image: Unanswered]

This question - the politics one - shows as unanswered, even though it has upvoted answers, one of which has been accepted. Is this a bug? Or is it intentional?